# How to make fixed-length vectors instance of Applicative?

Tags: haskell, types, pattern-matching, typeclass, gadt

I recently learned about promotion and decided to try writing vectors.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, GADTs, KindSignatures #-}
module Vector where
  data Nat = Next Nat | Zero
  data Vector :: Nat -> * -> * where
    Construct :: t -> Vector n t -> Vector ('Next n) t
    Empty :: Vector 'Zero t
  instance Functor (Vector n) where
    fmap f a =
      case a of
        Construct x b -> Construct (f x) (fmap f b)
        Empty -> Empty
```

So far, everything is working. But I ran into a problem when trying to make `Vector` instance of `Applicative`.

```
instance Applicative (Vector n) where
  a <*> b =
    case a of
      Construct f c ->
        case b of
          Construct x d -> Construct (f x) (c <*> d)
      Empty -> Empty
  pure x = _
```

I had no idea how to do `pure`. I tried this:

```
case n of
  Next _ -> Construct x (pure x)
  Zero -> Empty
```

but got `Variable not in scope: n :: Nat` error for the first line and `Couldn't match type n with 'Zero` for the third line of this expression.

So, I used the following hack.

```
class Applicative' n where
  ap' :: Vector n (t -> u) -> Vector n t -> Vector n u
  pure' :: t -> Vector n t
instance Applicative' n => Applicative' ('Next n) where
  ap' (Construct f a) (Construct x b) = Construct (f x) (ap' a b)
  pure' x = Construct x (pure' x)
instance Applicative' 'Zero where
  ap' Empty Empty = Empty
  pure' _ = Empty
instance Applicative' n => Applicative (Vector n) where
  (<*>) = ap'
  pure = pure'
```

It gets the job done, but it's not pretty. It introduces a useless class `Applicative'`. And every time I want to use `Applicative` for `Vector` in any function, I have to supply the additional useless constraint `Applicative' n` which actually holds for any `n`.

What would be a better, cleaner way of doing this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could make same directly:

```
instance Applicative (Vector Zero) where
  a <*> b = Empty
  pure x = Empty

instance Applicative (Vector n) => Applicative (Vector (Next n)) where
  a <*> b = 
    case a of
      Construct f c ->
        case b of
          Construct x d -> Construct (f x) (c <*> d)
  pure x = Construct x (pure x)
```

As I can reason about it: for different types of the class, the code should be type-aware. If you had several instances, different types would get different implementation, and it would be easily resolved. But, if you try to make it with single non-recursive instance, there is basically no information about the type in runtime, and code which is always the same still needs to decide which type to handle. When you have input parameters, you can exploit GADTs to provide you the type information. But for `pure` there are no input parameters. So you have to have some context for the `Applicative` instance.

Answer (score 2):

This is a (commented) alternative which exploits the `singletons` package.

Very roughly, Haskell does not let us pattern match on type-level values such as `n` in the code above. With `singletons`, we can, at the cost of requiring and providing a few instances of `SingI` here and there.

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs , KindSignatures, DataKinds, TemplateHaskell, 
             TypeFamilies, ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# OPTIONS -Wall #-}

import Data.Singletons.TH

-- Autogenerate singletons for this type
$(singletons [d|
   data Nat = Next Nat | Zero
   |])

-- as before
data Vector :: Nat -> * -> * where
   Construct :: t -> Vector n t -> Vector ('Next n) t
   Empty :: Vector 'Zero t

-- as before
instance Functor (Vector n) where
   fmap _ Empty = Empty
   fmap f (Construct x b) = Construct (f x) (fmap f b)        

-- We now require n to carry its own SingI instance.
-- This allows us to pattern match on n.
instance SingI n => Applicative (Vector n) where
   Empty <*> Empty = Empty
   -- Here, we need to access the singleton on n, so that later on we
   -- can provide the SingI (n-1) instance we need for the recursive call.
   -- The withSingI allows us to use m :: SNat (n-1) to provide the instance.
   (Construct f c) <*> (Construct x d) = case sing :: SNat n of
      SNext m -> withSingI m $ Construct (f x) (c <*> d)

   -- Here, we can finally pattern match on n.
   -- As above, we need to provide the instance with withSingI
   -- to the recursive call.
   pure x = case sing :: SNat n of
      SZero -> Empty
      SNext m -> withSingI m $ Construct x (pure x)
```

Using this will require to provide a `SingI n` instance at every use, which is a bit inconvenient, but not too much (IMO). The sad part is that `<*>` does not really need `SingI n`, since, in principle, it could recompute that from the two vectors at hand. However, `pure` has no input vector, so it can only pattern match with a provided singleton.

As another alternative, similar to the original code, one could write

```
instance Applicative (Vector Zero) where
   ...
instance Applicative (Vector n) => Applicative (Vector (Next n)) where
   ...
```

This is not completely equivalent, and will require to add contexts `Applicative (Vector n) =>` in all the functions later on where `n` is unknown, but could be enough for many purposes.

Comment: What is `$(singletons [d|` syntax? For example, what does it do in this case, for Nat? Could I also generate singletons manually, and if yes, then how? (Just trying to understand how it works.)

Comment: @Liisi There is a lot going on here. `$(singletons ...` is Template Haskell syntax, calling a `singletons` function during compile time. The function returns Haskell syntax which is then compiled. This will produce a GADT `SNat n` with constructors `SZero,SNext`, the idea being that there will be only one value of type `SNat n` for each `n`. In this way, compile time information on `n` is carried on at runtime. It is possible to define this manually (plus its `SingI` instances) but it is boring repetitive boilerplate. You can load the fine in GHCi and use `:i SNat` to see some of the result.

Answer (score 2):

Consider this an addendum to @chi's answer to provide additional explanation of the singleton approach...

I would suggest reading the [Hasochism paper](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/slindley/papers/hasochism.pdf) if you haven't already done so.  In particular, in section 3.1 of that paper, they deal with exactly this problem, and use it as the motivating example for when implicit singleton parameters (the `SingI` of @chi's answer, and the `NATTY` type class in the Hasochism paper) are necessary, rather than merely convenient.

As it applies to your code, the main issue is that `pure` needs a run-time representation of the length of the vector that it's supposed to be generating, and the type-level variable `n` doesn't fit the bill.  The solution is to introduce a new GADT, a "singleton" that provides runtime values that correspond directly to the promoted types `Next` and `Zero`:

```
data Natty (n :: Nat) where
  ZeroTy :: Natty Zero
  NextTy :: Natty n -> Natty (Next n)
```

I tried to use roughly the same naming convention as the paper:  `Natty` is the same, and `ZeroTy` and `NextTy` correspond to the paper's `Zy` and `Sy`.

By itself, this explicit singleton is useful.  For example, see the definition of `vchop` in the paper.  Also, we can easily write a variant of `pure` that takes the explicit singleton to do its job:

```
vcopies :: Natty n -> a -> Vector n a
vcopies ZeroTy _ = Empty
vcopies (NextTy n) x = Construct x (vcopies n x)
```

We can't yet use this to define `pure`, though, because `pure`'s signature is determined by the `Applicative` type class, and we have no way to squeeze the explicit singleton `Natty n` in there.

The solution is to introduce implicit singletons, which allow us to retrieve an explicit singleton whenever needed through the `natty` function in the context of the following type class:

```
class NATTY n where
  natty :: Natty n
instance NATTY Zero where
  natty = ZeroTy
instance NATTY n => NATTY (Next n) where
  natty = NextTy natty
```

Now, provided we're in a `NATTY n` context, we can call `vcopies natty` to supply `vcopies` with its explicit `natty` parameter, which allows us to write:

```
instance NATTY n => Applicative (Vector n) where
  (<*>) = vapp
  pure = vcopies natty
```

using the definitions of `vcopies` and `natty` above, and the definition of `vapp` below:

```
vapp :: Vector n (a -> b) -> Vector n a -> Vector n b
vapp Empty Empty = Empty
vapp (Construct f c) (Construct x d) = Construct (f x) (vapp c d)
```

Note one oddity.  We needed to introduce this `vapp` helper function for an obscure reason.  The following instance *without* `NATTY` matches your `case`-based definition and type-checks fine:

```
instance Applicative (Vector n) where
  Empty <*> Empty = Empty
  Construct f c <*> Construct x d = Construct (f x) (c <*> d)
  pure = error "Argh!  No NATTY!"
```

If we add the `NATTY` constraint to define `pure`:

```
instance NATTY n => Applicative (Vector n) where
  Empty <*> Empty = Empty
  Construct f c <*> Construct x d = Construct (f x) (c <*> d)
  pure = vcopies natty
```

the definition of `(<*>)` doesn't type check any more.  The problem is that the `NATTY n` constraint on the left-hand side of the second `(<*>)` case doesn't automatically imply a `NATTY n1` constraint on the right-hand side (where `Next n ~ n1`), so GHC doesn't want to allow us to call `(<*>)` on the right-hand side.  In this case, because the constraint isn't actually needed after it's used for the first time, a helper function without a `NATTY` constraint, namely `vapp`, works around the problem.

@chi uses case matching on `natty` and the helper function `withSingI` as an alternative workaround.  The equivalent code here would use a helper function that turns an explicit singleton into an implicit `NATTY` context:

```
withNATTY :: Natty n -> (NATTY n => a) -> a
withNATTY ZeroTy a = a
withNATTY (NextTy n) a = withNATTY n a
```

allowing us to write:

```
instance NATTY n => Applicative (Vector n) where
  Empty <*> Empty = Empty
  Construct f c <*> Construct x d = case (natty :: Natty n) of
    NextTy n -> withNATTY n $ Construct (f x) (c <*> d)
  pure x = case (natty :: Natty n) of
    ZeroTy -> Empty
    NextTy n -> Construct x (withNATTY n $ pure x)
```

This would need both `ScopedTypeVariables` and `RankNTypes`.

Anyway, sticking with the helper functions, the complete program looks like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, GADTs, KindSignatures #-}

module Vector where

data Nat = Next Nat | Zero
data Vector :: Nat -> * -> * where
  Construct :: t -> Vector n t -> Vector ('Next n) t
  Empty :: Vector 'Zero t

data Natty (n :: Nat) where
  ZeroTy :: Natty Zero
  NextTy :: Natty n -> Natty (Next n)

class NATTY n where
  natty :: Natty n
instance NATTY Zero where
  natty = ZeroTy
instance NATTY n => NATTY (Next n) where
  natty = NextTy natty

instance Functor (Vector n) where
  fmap f a =
    case a of
      Construct x b -> Construct (f x) (fmap f b)
      Empty -> Empty

instance NATTY n => Applicative (Vector n) where
  (<*>) = vapp
  pure = vcopies natty

vapp :: Vector n (a -> b) -> Vector n a -> Vector n b
vapp Empty Empty = Empty
vapp (Construct f c) (Construct x d) = Construct (f x) (vapp c d)

vcopies :: Natty n -> a -> Vector n a
vcopies ZeroTy _ = Empty
vcopies (NextTy n) x = Construct x (vcopies n x)
```

The correspondence with the `singletons` library is that:

```
$(singletons [d|
  data Nat = Next Nat | Zero
  |])
```

automatically generates the singletons (with constructors `SZero` and `SNat` instead of `ZeroTy` and `NatTy`; and with type `SNat` instead of `Natty`) and the implicit singleton class (called `SingI` instead of `NATTY` and using the function `sing` instead of `natty`), giving the complete program:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, GADTs, KindSignatures, TemplateHaskell, TypeFamilies #-}

module Vector where

import Data.Singletons
import Data.Singletons.TH

$(singletons [d|
  data Nat = Next Nat | Zero
  |])

data Vector :: Nat -> * -> * where
  Construct :: t -> Vector n t -> Vector ('Next n) t
  Empty :: Vector 'Zero t

instance Functor (Vector n) where
  fmap f a =
    case a of
      Construct x b -> Construct (f x) (fmap f b)
      Empty -> Empty

instance SingI n => Applicative (Vector n) where
  (<*>) = vapp
  pure = vcopies sing

vapp :: Vector n (a -> b) -> Vector n a -> Vector n b
vapp Empty Empty = Empty
vapp (Construct f c) (Construct x d) = Construct (f x) (vapp c d)

vcopies :: SNat n -> a -> Vector n a
vcopies SZero _ = Empty
vcopies (SNext n) x = Construct x (vcopies n x)
```

For more on what the `singletons` library does and how it's built, I'd suggest reading [Introduction to Singletons](https://blog.jle.im/entries/series/+introduction-to-singletons.html).

Comment: I really like your `vapp`/`vcopies` approach. It's very clean.

Answer (score 1):

Several other answers have introduced a `Natty` or `SNat` type to implement `pure`. Indeed, having such a type greatly reduces the need for one-off type classes. A potential downside of the traditional `Natty`/`SNat` GADT, however, is that your program will actually build the representation and then use it, even if the `Nat` is known at compile time. This generally *wouldn't* happen with the auxiliary-class approach. You can get around this by using a different representation.

I'm going to use these names:

```
data Nat = Z | S Nat
```

Suppose we define the usual

```
data Natty n where
  Zy :: Natty 'Z
  Sy :: Natty n -> Natty ('S n)
```

We can write its eliminator (induction principle) thus:

```
natty :: p 'Z -> (forall k. p k -> p ('S k)) -> Natty n -> p n
natty z _ Zy = z
natty z s (Sy n) = s (natty z s n)
```

For our purpose, we don't really need the `Natty`; we only need its induction principle! So let's define another version. I imagine there's a proper name for this encoding, but I have no idea what it might be.

```
newtype NatC n = NatC
  { unNatC :: forall p.
              p 'Z  -- base case
           -> (forall k. p k -> p ('S k))  -- inductive step
           -> p n }
```

This is isomorphic to `Natty`:

```
nattyToNatC :: Natty n -> NatC n
nattyToNatC n = NatC (\z s -> natty z s n)

natCToNatty :: NatC n -> Natty n
natCToNatty (NatC f) = f Zy Sy
```

Now we can write a class for `Nat`s we know how to eliminate:

```
class KnownC n where
  knownC :: NatC n
instance KnownC 'Z where
  knownC = NatC $ \z _ -> z
instance KnownC n => KnownC ('S n) where
  knownC = NatC $ \z s -> s $ unNatC knownC z s
```

Now here's a vector type (I've renamed things to match my own taste):

```
infixr 4 :<
data Vec :: Nat -> * -> * where
  (:<) :: t -> Vec n t -> Vec ('S n) t
  Nil :: Vec 'Z t
```

Because `Vec`'s length parameter isn't its last one, we'll have to flip it to use with `NatC`:

```
newtype Flip f a n = {unFlip :: f n a}

induct2 :: f 'Z a
         -> (forall k. f k a -> f ('S k) a)
         -> NatC n -> f n a
induct2 z s n = unFlip $ unNatC n (Flip z) (\(Flip r) -> Flip (s r))

replC :: NatC n -> a -> Vec n a
replC n a = induct2 Nil (a :<) n

instance KnownC n => Applicative (Vec n) where
   pure = replC knownC
   (<*>) = ...
```

Now if the vector length is known at compile time, the `pure` vector will be built directly, with no intermediate structure needed.