# How to define a usable Applicative instance for a vector type enforcing length 2^n

Tags: haskell

For some application I need vectors of length $2^n$. To enforce that the lengths match for some operations, I defined my type with ist applicative instance as follows:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, DataKinds, FlexibleInstances, FlexibleContexts #-}
data Nat = Z | N Nat
data Vector n t where
  S :: t -> Vector Z t
  V :: Vector n t -> Vector n t -> Vector (N n) t

instance Functor (Vector n) where
  fmap f (S t ) = S (f t)
  fmap f (V t t') = V (fmap f t) (fmap f t')

instance Applicative (Vector Z) where
  pure = S
  S f <*> S a = S (f a)

instance Applicative (Vector n) => Applicative (Vector (N n)) where
  pure a = let a' = pure a in V a' a'
  V f f' <*> V a a' = V (f <*> a) (f' <*> a')
```

The language extensions I chose as suggested by ghci to make the code compile. The whole structure is inspired by [How to make fixed-length vectors instance of Applicative?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49206636/how-to-make-fixed-length-vectors-instance-of-applicative).

Trouble starts when I try to use it:

```
instance Num t => Num (Vector n t) where
  v + v' = (+) <$> v <*> v'
  (*) = undefined
  abs = undefined
  signum = undefined
  fromInteger = undefined
  negate = undefined
```

Adding these lines Triggers following error:

• Could not deduce (Applicative (Vector n))
        arising from a use of ‘<*>’
      from the context: Num t
        bound by the instance declaration at ...

• In the expression: (+)  v <*> v'
      In an equation for ‘+’: v + v' = (+)  v <*> v'
      In the instance declaration for ‘Num (Vector n t)’

I'm using Haskell Platform 8.0.2-a on Windows 7.

Any idea what's going? In the linked question the same trick seems to work!? (Adding KindSignatures in the first line does not help, and without FlexibleInstances/Contexts I get a Compiler error.)

Comment: You should write it like `instance (Num t, Applicative (Vector n)) => Num (Vector n t) where` since otherwise you can indeed not use `(<*>)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I somehow wrongly assumed that the compiler knows that all (Vector n) are Applicatives.

Comment: @JohnPoe Counter-intuitively, not all of them are applicatives, for very subtle reasons. If `F x :: Nat` is a type family which gets "stuck" (say, `F Bool` is not defined) the compiler is not allowed to resolve, say, `Applicative (Vector (F Bool))` since it can not evaluate `F Bool` to a concrete `Nat`, so it can not choose an instance. It is weird to have type-expressions of kind `Nat` which do not evaluate to a concrete `Nat`, but that's how GHC works.

Comment: @chi: Thank you very much for your explanation, but it might be beyond my current understanding of haskell. Do I understand correctly that the problem is the n in Vector n t, as the compiler has to be able to prove that it is either a Z or N x for a concrete Nat x, which it cannot, as someone might plug in a "weird thing" for n that only "claims" to be a Nat?

Comment: @JohnPoe Yes, that's a nice way to put it. Your instances will be used only when there is an explicit `Z` or `N x` in the type. If there is a type variable like `n` or a "stuck" type family `F Bool`, GHC does not know what instance to pick and will not resolve the constraint. There are some ways around that, e.g. exploiting suitable GADTs to prove "`n` is indeed one of the two possible forms" -- this is a bit advanced, however, so I'd recommend to get familiar with GADTs first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should add a type constraint in your `Num (Vector n t)` instance declaration, that specifies that `Vector n a` is an instance of `Applicative`, otherwise you can not use `(<*>)` here.

You thus can fix the problems with:

```
instance (Num t, Applicative (Vector n)) => Num (Vector n t) where
  v + v' = (+) <$> v <*> v'
  -- ...
```

We here thus say that `Vector n t` is an instance of `Num` given `t` is an instance of `Num`, and `Vector n` is an instance of `Applicative`.

Since you defined your `instance Applicative` for your `Vector n` in such way that it holds for all `n`s, all `Vector n t`s are members of `Num` given `Num t`, regardless of the value for `n`, but it needs to be part of the signature of the `instance` declaration.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's a bit nicer to use an auxiliary class. I also tend to prefer `liftA2` to `<*>` for instances, so I'll use that; it's not essential. Note that you only need to differentiate between sizes for `pure`; the zipping operation doesn't need that. There's a trade-off: if you make the zipping operation a method, then it'll tend to inline, whereas if it's a function it generally won't. This could balance code size against speed when the vectors are small enough. Still, this is how I'd probably do it.

```
class App' n where
  pure' :: a -> Vector n a

instance App' 'Z where
  pure' = S

instance App' n => App' ('N n) where
  pure' a = let a' = pure' a in V a' a'

liftA2'
  :: (a -> b -> c)
  -> Vector n a
  -> Vector n b
  -> Vector n c
liftA2' f = \xs -> go xs
  where
    go (S x) (S y) = S (f x y)
    go (V l1 r1) (V l2 r2) =
      V (go l1 l2) (go r1 r2)

instance App' n => Applicative (Vector n) where
  pure = pure'
  -- import Control.Applicative to get the liftA2 method
  liftA2 = liftA2'
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't quite see the advantage of the auxiliary class (yet), but I guess if the implementation of <*> or liftA2 was a bit more complex, then the balance would shift also for me.

Comment: A question to function vs. method: What's the difference? Is a function simply something defined on the outer level and a method defined in a where let?